# Sorting two separate Lists in the same order?

Tags: c#, .net

Just to lay down some restrictions first. Because of the environment I'm coding this in, I cannot create my own classes or methods. Just basic procedural code. It's in a CMS, and my code is executed inside a method itself.

**Here's my question**

On this page, I do a database query, loading all 700ish store locations. I then do a distance calculation based on the lat and lng values in the query string against the ones in the database to find the stores within 50 kilometers. Each one that is within that distance, I currently add to a `List<DataRow>`. I also take the distance result, round it to one decimal place, and store that into a simple list of type Double. What I want to do, is basically sort these so when i output the stores + distance value, it is sorted shortest to longest distance. I was thinking of switching the `List<DataRow>` and `List<Double>` combo to a `Dictionary<Double, DataRow>` and use sorting there, but there is of course certain cases where two places have the same distance value, so therefore it would not be unique. Is there another collection type I can use for this, or can you recommend a good way to sort the data?

**Here's my code in case you need a visual:**

The PRA object is basically the main object we use for working with the backend aspects of our CMS. In this case I'm using a short hand method to query the data, and check a couple variables in the request data. The rest is all built in .net stuff.

```
List<DataRow> locationsInRange = new List<DataRow>();
List<Double> distances = new List<Double>();
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(PRA.Request.QueryString["lat"]) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(PRA.Request.QueryString["lng"])) {
  Double earthRadius = 6371.0;
  Double maxDistance = 50.0;

  var locations = PRA.QueryDataRows("*", "", "{Location}", "showweb");
  Double lat =  Double.Parse(PRA.Request.QueryString["lat"]);
  Double lng =  Double.Parse(PRA.Request.QueryString["lng"]);

  if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(PRA.Request.QueryString["radius"])) {
    Double temp = Double.Parse(PRA.Request.QueryString["radius"]);
    if(temp > 0) {
      maxDistance = temp;
    }
  }

  bool firstError = true;
  foreach(var l in locations) {
    Double latSecond = 0.0;
    Double lngSecond = 0.0;
    try {
      latSecond = Double.Parse(l["lat"].ToString());
      lngSecond = Double.Parse(l["lng"].ToString());
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
      // do nothing. The lat and lng may not of been valid or not returned a result
    }


    Double dLat = Math.PI * ((lat - latSecond) / 180.0);
    Double dLon = Math.PI * ((lng - lngSecond) / 180.0);

    Double lat1 = Math.PI * (latSecond / 180.0);
    Double lat2 = Math.PI * (lat / 180.0);

    Double a = Math.Sin(dLat / 2) * Math.Sin(dLat / 2) + Math.Sin(dLon / 2) * Math.Sin(dLon / 2) * Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Cos(lat2);
    Double c = 2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(a), Math.Sqrt(1 - a));
    if(earthRadius * c <= (Double) maxDistance) {
      locationsInRange.Add(l);
      distances.Add(Math.Round(earthRadius * c, 1));
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Most databases have this feature built into it ... [Spatial_Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_index#Spatial_Index).. you shouldn't be doing this manually

Comment: That's actually a very interesting point. Right now, the lat & lng values are currently stored in varchar. Our CMS tables that we setup for each client site doesn't support this data type, however I am definitely going to speak to them about it, as moving forward this would be very very useful.

Comment: Voting to close: "I cannot create my own classes or methods"  That's way too localized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list of pairs (data, distance), represented by the `Tuple` type...

```
var locations = new List<Tuple<DataRow, double>>();
locations.Add(Tuple.Create(row, distance));
locations.Sort((x, y) => x.Item2.CompareTo(y.Item2));
```

Comment: Thanks so much, i had to make one minor correction to the last line, but that did the trick: `locations.Sort((x, y) => x.Item2.CompareTo(y.Item2));`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the var keyword in the middle of the method to get the compiler to generate an anonymous class.

```
var combinedInstance = new {Row = new DataRow(), Distance = 0.0m};
```

You can use lambda notation in the middle of the method to get the compiler to generate new methods.

```
Func<Location, Location, decimal> getDistance = (loc1, loc2) =>
{
  return 0.0m; //TODO implement
}
```

---

```
var combinedList = locationsInRange
  .Select((row, i) => new {Row = row, Distance = distances[i]})
  .OrderBy(x => x.Distance)
  .ToList();
// now replace the original lists with newly ordered lists.
locationsInRange = combinedList.Select(x => x.Row).ToList();
distances = combinedList.Select(x => x.Distance).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If refactoring into a single datatype is not an option, you can sort the indices and work with a lookup table. This worked well enough for interfacing with some legacy code base.

Standalone example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Some disjoint datasets
        List<int> scores = new List<int>{3,5,2,8,4};
        List<string> names = new List<string>{"three","five","two","eight","four"};

        // Sequence of indices
        List<int> indices = new List<int>(System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(0, scores.Count));

        // Sort indices, based on corresponding score
        indices.Sort(delegate(int a, int b) { return scores[a] - scores[b]; });

        for(int i = 0; i < indices.Count; ++i) 
        {
            // Use lookup table for indices
            int index = indices[i];
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: {0}, score: {1}", names[index], scores[index]));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The clean way would be to create an `ICompareable` class holding a `DataRow` and a `Double`, with the comparison defaulting to the comparison of the `Double`. You could then use a `SortedList` for a natural representation.

Since this clean way is impossible according to the (first overread by me) design of the app, we need a dirty way, and my suggestion is

- Assuming you have SOME unique value in your shop list (location seems to be one)
- create a string representation of sorts `String.Format("{0:0000000000}/{1}",Math.Round(distance*10000),unique_criterium)`
- Store this in a SortedList
- When iterating the SortedList, resolve the String back

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for the suggestion, but as per the top of my post, I cannot define any classes or methods :(. The body of code I use for a template is actually pulled into a method block, and then is compiled. Perhaps this isn't the strongest design for the platform, but I imagine it was a solution best thought at the time for the timeframe the development had.